# Compare two images, where the one is slightly cropped (zoomed)

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

Im using the image library `rmagick` for ruby to compare two images, in order to detect, if they are actually the same image (avoid duplications).

They way I'm usually doing it, is by using the [difference](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#difference) method:

```
require 'rmagick'

img1.difference(img2)
#=> [238.738932291668, 0.001389172567175018, 0.0184313725490196]
```

The above example is the output of two images which is most certainly the same. This used to work very well for me, until I stumbled into a new scenario, that this method does not handle very well - if the images are the same (even same size), but one of them has been cropped e.g. 10px of the border. Now suddenly, even though the two images look exactly the same to the human eye, the computer will think they are very different, because one of the images has been cropped just a small bit.

Is there anyway I can handle this situation, so I will still detect that it's the same image, even though one of them has been cropped a little?

Comment: This is a tricky subject area. There are lots of possible valid crops, and it is not 100% clear how extreme a crop you'd want to allow. You need to define "same" quite carefully. It is probably a good idea to give your goal for image matching - not that it is necessarily achievable, but it may help move away from solving machine vision, which a question like this could devolve into.

Comment: Surely a deliberately-cropped image is not a duplicate, if this is for e.g. a CMS, then you might consider the cropped version a *revision* of the original. It's just a subtle edit. What kind of duplication are you trying to avoid - copyright violation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your example pictures might look very similar to a human, the raw image data looks very different.

You need some more sophisticated image processing algorithm which does not compare raw data, but which is invariant to operations like transformation, scaling or rotation.

Generally, I would advise you to use a computer vision library like [OpenCV](http://opencv.org); it also has [ruby bindings](https://github.com/ruby-opencv/ruby-opencv). You might look at so-called [Image Moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment) in [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html) part of the documentation. The normalized central moments nu_ij should be invariant to translation and scaling; if you calculate these for both images and compare them, you should get near-identical values for a slightly cropped image.